# How to copy files in text to, to specified path in same text file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a text file containing file names and the path where they are intended to go, delimited by a comma. I need to create a batch file to search one directory for the files, and copy them to their respective destinations.

The text file looks like this:

```
12345.pdf, C:\SomeDirectory\1 
54321.pdf, C:\SomeDirectory\2
67891.pdf, C:\SomeDirectory\3
```

The pdf files are all in a single folder with no subdirectories. The command would pick up the file names before the comma, find the files in the source, and copy them to the path stated after the comma on the same line in the text file.

I am assuming PowerShell would also be an option.

Here is what I have tried:

```
FOR /F  "tokens=1,2" delims =," %%G IN (PDF_MISSING.txt) DO @echo copy /Y "W:\GasImages\ServiceCards\All_PDF\%%G" "%%H"
```

Also:

```
FOR /F  "tokens=1,2" delims =," %%G IN (PDF_MISSING.txt) DO @echo copy /Y "W:\GasImages\ServiceCards\All_PDF\%%G" "%%H"
```

Both of these return "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: Would trying telling us what you tried so far also be an option? You do realize that you're expected to try it yourself first, don't you?

Comment: Actually you don't even need to program, just use a text editor with regexp-replace: `^(.+?), (.+)$` to `copy $1 $2` (or `copy \1 \2`), save it in the folder with pdfs as `copypdfs.bat` and run it.

Comment: wOxxOm, can you be a bit more specific? What are the steps? Not sure what you mean, thanks.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think he addressed your comment

Comment: @Isaac And you're bringing that up 2.5 years later ... why exactly?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers just tryna keep some questions and answers clean. Looks like people downvoted this question and forgot about it

Comment: Not me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong Syntax. Correct Syntax:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN ...
```

Note: the space (after the comma) will be part of the value of `%%H`

You could add the space to the delimiters, but then you'll have a Problem, when any path contains an intended space. If you are sure, there won't be one:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, " %%G IN ...
```